# How to use multiple storage option in redux-persist

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I have this `redux` setup , i have number of reducers for auth ruducer i want to use localstorage and for rest reducers i want to use session storage . How to do that

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import { persistStore, persistReducer, createTransform } from "redux-persist";
    import rootReducer from "./reducers";
    import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";
    import { parse, stringify } from "flatted";
    import { apiSlice } from "apiHelpers/ApiSlice";
    import sessionStorage from "redux-persist/lib/storage/session";
    
  
    
    const persistConfig = {
      key: "root",
      storage: sessionStorage,
      whitelist: [
        "cart",
        
      ],
    };
    
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
    
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          sentryReduxEnhancer,
          serializableCheck: false,
        })
      
    });
    
    
    
    setupListeners(store.dispatch);
    export const persistor = persistStore(store);
    export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nested Persists](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#nested-persists)

> Nested persist can be useful for including different storage adapters, code splitting, or deep filtering.

Set local storage for auth reducer, set session storage for root reducer **exclude** auth reducer via `blacklist` option.

E.g.

```
import localStorage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import storageSession from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/session';
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';

const authPersistConfig = {
  key: 'auth',
  storage: localStorage,
};

const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storageSession,
  blacklist: ['auth'],
};

const authReducer = (state = { name: 'auth' }) => state;
const otherReducer = (state = { name: 'other' }) => state;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: persistReducer(authPersistConfig, authReducer),
  other: otherReducer,
});

const persistRootReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(persistRootReducer);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Data in local storage:

```
localStorage.getItem('persist:auth')
// "{"name":"\"auth\"","_persist":"{\"version\":-1,\"rehydrated\":true}"}"
```

Data in session storage:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('persist:root')

// "{"other":"{\"name\":\"other\"}","_persist":"{\"version\":-1,\"rehydrated\":true}"}"
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ykbyf5?file=src%2Fstore.ts)

Comment: can you do in my example as i have already created root reducer file